# Best way to access enum in Amplify graphql schema

Tags: enums, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, amplifyjs

We are using enums in our graphql schema in Amplify/AppSync.

We are confused as to what Amplify enforces and how to use the enums.
Simply saving the string values works fine but we'd really like to limit available options to enums to add integrity to the code.

What is the best way to save an enum using a mutator and to compare queried values using the enum.
The generated /src/graphql files don't seem to expose the enum values.